# Creating a dynamic rule in prolog

Tags: prolog, erlog

I am working on the Erlog system and trying to create some code to allow better integration with erlang records. As such I would like to be able to take a record name and a list of fields and create prolog rules from them. What I want is that given a record in erlang called person, with the fields, [name, phone] that I would end up with rules like this

```
person(name, Person, Name) :- arg(2, Person, Name).
person(phone, Person, Phone):- arg(3, Person, Phone).
```

And that this should be able to happen pretty easily. So what I had thought to do was to create a new rule, that would be dynamicly named. This is what I tried, but it won't compile.

```
make_access(_, [], _) :-!.
make_access(RecordName, [Field|Rest], Place) :-
    asserta((RecordName(Field,Record,Value) :- arg(Place, Record, Value))),
    N is Place + 1,
    make_access(RecordName, Rest, N).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a variable as a functor:

```
RecordName(Field,Record,Value)
```

Instead you can construct the term e.g. with `=..`:

```
Rule =.. [RecordName,Field,Record,Value]
```

The first element in the list on the right hand side of `=..` is the functor of the term, the rest are the arguments.

Then you can just continue:

```
asserta((Rule :- arg(Place, Record, Value)))
```

(I haven't checked the rest of your example if it does what you want to achieve).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, after I found and fixed a bug in erlog